# Converting Quill Delta Mention to TipTap Mention

Tags: reactjs, quill, tiptap

Is there a way to add a mention to a TipTap rich text editor via JSONContent?

`index.cjs:1591 [tiptap warn]: Invalid content. Passed value: {type: 'doc', content: Array(3)} Error: RangeError: Unknown node type: mention` is logged to the console when setting a TipTap rich text editor's content with the following JSONContent:

```
{ 
   type: 'doc',
   content: [{
      type: "mention",
      attrs: {
         id: op.insert['mention'].id,
         label: op.insert['mention'].value,
      }
   }]
}
```

where `op.insert['mention'].id` is the mention Id from the Quill Delta and `op.insert['mention'].value` is the mention label from the Quill Delta.

TipTap should allow JSONContent and HTML; however, it seems to only handle mentions via HTML (e.g., `<p><span data-type="mention" class="mention" data-id="<ID>" data-label="admin user">@admin user</span> </p>`)

Edit: Add full warning:

```
index.cjs:1591 [tiptap warn]: Invalid content. Passed value: 
{type: 'doc', content: Array(3)}
 Error: RangeError: Unknown node type: mention
    at Schema.nodeType (index.cjs:2347:1)
    at Function.fromJSON (index.cjs:1404:1)
    at Schema.nodeFromJSON (index.cjs:2336:1)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.fromJSON (index.cjs:372:1)
    at Function.fromJSON (index.cjs:1403:1)
    at Schema.nodeFromJSON (index.cjs:2336:1)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.fromJSON (index.cjs:372:1)
    at Function.fromJSON (index.cjs:1403:1)
createNodeFromContent   @   index.cjs:1591
createDocument  @   index.cjs:1940
createView  @   index.cjs:3478
Editor  @   index.cjs:3329
Editor  @   index.cjs:42
(anonymous) @   index.cjs:434
invokePassiveEffectCreate   @   react-dom.development.js:23479
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4056
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @   react-dom.development.js:23566
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11268
flushPassiveEffects @   react-dom.development.js:23439
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:22261
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:11319
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11268
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:11314
flushSyncCallbackQueue  @   react-dom.development.js:11301
scheduleUpdateOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:21885
enqueueSetState @   react-dom.development.js:12459
Component.setState  @   react.development.js:365
(anonymous) @   NewsFeedItem.tsx:1367
Promise.then (async)        
showComments    @   NewsFeedItem.tsx:1323
componentDidMount   @   NewsFeedItem.tsx:199
commitLifeCycles    @   react-dom.development.js:20655
commitLayoutEffects @   react-dom.development.js:23418
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:23143
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11268
commitRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:22982
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:22321
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:11319
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11268
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:11314
flushSyncCallbackQueue  @   react-dom.development.js:11301
scheduleUpdateOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:21885
enqueueSetState @   react-dom.development.js:12459
Component.setState  @   react.development.js:365
(anonymous) @   HomePage.tsx:84
Promise.then (async)        
componentDidMount   @   HomePage.tsx:63
commitLifeCycles    @   react-dom.development.js:20655
commitLayoutEffects @   react-dom.development.js:23418
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:23143
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11268
commitRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:22982
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:22321
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:11319
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11268
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:11314
flushSyncCallbackQueue  @   react-dom.development.js:11301
scheduleUpdateOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:21885
enqueueSetState @   react-dom.development.js:12459
Component.setState  @   react.development.js:365
(anonymous) @   Navbar.tsx:376
Promise.then (async)        
componentDidMount   @   Navbar.tsx:370
commitLifeCycles    @   react-dom.development.js:20655
commitLayoutEffects @   react-dom.development.js:23418
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:23143
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11268
commitRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:22982
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:22321
scheduleUpdateOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:21873
updateContainer @   react-dom.development.js:25474
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:26013
unbatchedUpdates    @   react-dom.development.js:22423
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer    @   react-dom.development.js:26012
render  @   react-dom.development.js:26095
(anonymous) @   HomePage.tsx:485
```

Comment: It's telling you that `mention` is a non-existent type (presumably on line 4 of what you're showing, but you're not actually showing the full error, so you're asking people to guess. [Don't ask people to guess](/help/how-to-ask)), so: did you look up which types are allowed?

Comment: TipTap uses a schema for the editor, and it only allows nodes that follow that said schema. When you initialize your editor you need to pass in an extension that defines how to handle a `mention` node. You can check their website for existing extensions, or make your own.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I've added the full warning to the original post. I would think `mention` is a valid type considering `editor.getJSON()' returns the following object: {attrs: {id: '6499a7755a131489020ed8fa', label: 'Conversation'}, type: "mention"}.

Comment: And yet, the error rather explicitly says it's an unknown type. So: which types did you register? Is the `mention` extension loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I was conditionally adding the Mention extension; however, the conditional wasn't working as expected and I wasn't actually adding the Mention extension.

Comment: Note that this is not an answer (yet). If you want this to be an answer, show what you did (in [mcve] form) and then talk about what you did to that to fix it (and _why_ that fix works of course). See the ["How to write a good answer"](/help/how-to-answer) policy article for the guidelines when writing an answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).